# How to get variable's value from js to index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my javascript file which contain like this

```
//custom.js
var setting = {
lastDate: '06/01/2016 09:18:00',   //Date format: month/day/year hours:minutes:seconds
timeZone: GMT +8,                    //GMT +10 or -5
style:{
    colorStart:'#3CEAEE',          //Background color start. Any #hex color, only 6 characters
    colorEnd:'#0d4266',            //Background color end. Any #hex color, only 6 characters
    bgStyle:'circularMiddleCenter' //Background style
}
};
```

So in my index.html. how do i get the lastDate value from the js file and do comparison?

My index.html have a button which always in disable mode, and when the lastDate reached, concept using current Date - lastDate. then the button will be enabled back and do actions.

```
<button>Let's Go</button>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: so do you means that : if the current date reach the "last date", then enable the button?

Comment: For starters what is source of the dates? Should add a property that stores a javascript compatible date value also that can be passed easily to `Date()` object without a bunch of parsing

Comment: Yes correct @JackyShek.

Comment: Can you teach me ? @charlietfl

Comment: Teach what? This isn't a tutorial service. The acceptable formats are easy to research and are well documented in many places

Comment: Using much Google can help you to reach your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `new Date()` to get the current time to do your purpose

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        //custom.js
        var setting = {
          lastDate: '5/30/2016 09:18:00', //Date format: month/day/year hours:minutes:seconds
          timeZone: "GMT +8", //GMT +10 or -5
          style: {
            colorStart: '#3CEAEE', //Background color start. Any #hex color, only 6 characters
            colorEnd: '#0d4266', //Background color end. Any #hex color, only 6 characters
            bgStyle: 'circularMiddleCenter' //Background style
          }
        };
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log((new Date().getTime() / 1000));
          if ((new Date(setting.lastDate).getTime() / 1000) <= (new Date().getTime() / 1000)) {
            alert("reach");
          }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Your code failed to work. Example. when i try to paste it and run, when time reach the message box didn't display. i have to refresh the page only it appear. but i hope it like directly display it if the date reach

Comment: @user2422414 what is the day of today?  You should check it before said it failed.

Comment: @user2422414 I have change the date. I have used the date that you have provide. so before you said it failed, please go to try the answer not just paste and run.